# Moneris Vault check if card exist

Tags: payment, payment-processing

I am using the Moneris eSelectPlus and I store credit cards in the Vault and access it using the token. Is there a way to check if a credit card has already been stored in the Vault before?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the **data_key** of the Vault profile (which is probably stored locally in your application and attached to a user), you can inspect the cards stored by using *ResLookupFull* or *ResLookupMasked* (Administrative Transactions).

Note: you can access the guides at [developer.moneris.com](https://developer.moneris.com).